# Need help in read attribute /field values from XML using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

Team,

I would like to extract values from node '<d:personIdExternal>55229507</d:personIdExternal>' in to   variable.  In the XML there will be multiple  d:personIdExternal value but i want to pick first one. In the below example I want to retrieve '**55229507**'

```html
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
          xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
          xml:base="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/">
       <title type="text">PerPerson</title>
       <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerPerson</id>
       <updated>2022-11-07T02:42:45Z</updated>
       <link href="PerPerson" rel="self" title="PerPerson"/>
       <entry>
          <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerPerson('55229507')</id>
          <title type="text"/>
          <updated>2022-11-07T02:42:45Z</updated>
          <author>
             <name/>
          </author>
          <link href="PerPerson('55229507')" rel="edit" title="PerPerson"/>
          <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
                    term="SFOData.PerPerson"/>
          <content type="application/xml">
             <m:properties>
                <d:personIdExternal>55229507</d:personIdExternal>
             </m:properties>
          </content>
       <entry>
          <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerPerson('ZZ01058714')</id>
          <title type="text"/>
          <updated>2022-11-07T02:42:45Z</updated>
          <author>
             <name/>
          </author>
          <link href="PerPerson('ZZ01058714')" rel="edit" title="PerPerson"/>
          <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
                    term="SFOData.PerPerson"/>
          <content type="application/xml">
             <m:properties>
                <d:personIdExternal>ZZ01058714</d:personIdExternal>
             </m:properties>
          </content>
       </entry>
       <link href="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerPerson?$select=personIdExternal&amp;$skiptoken=eyJzdGFydFJvdyI6MTAwMCwiZW5kUm93IjoyMDAwfQ=="
             rel="next"/>
    </feed>
```

Tried to use something like this but couldn't work , idea is here to bring output in xml

```html
let $input:= /feed
for $i in $input//entry
return
<Element>
<personIdExternal>{$i/properties/personIdExternal/text()}</personIdExternal>
</Element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is in a namespace so use e.g.

```
declare namespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

(//d:personIdExternal)[1]
```

to just select the element or if needed e.g.

```
declare namespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

<Element><personalIdExternal>{data((//d:personIdExternal)[1])}</personalIdExternal></Element>
```

to wrap its data into some new content structure

Comment: thanks, Martin, for the suggestion.  Actually, Xquery supposed to be used in a tool called Informatica cloud, but it seems it won't support delcare name space . May be it should be something like https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/514052?language=en_US  It would be great help if you can look in to the example in link , sorry my knowledge Xquery is limited